# from the 16th century downward?

Tags: vocabulary

I'd like to know what the difference is between "from the 16th century downward", "from the 16th century onwards", and "since the 16th century".

> [Many polyglot collections of the prayer have been published from the 16th century downward.](http://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Encyclopedia_Americana_%281920%29/Lord%27s_Prayer,_The)

Comment: I have not seen nor heard "downward" to refer to time like in your example "from the 16th century downward". I reviewed Google Web Search results for the quoted phrase "century downward" and most of the results seem to be Biblical in nature or questions like this one, asking about this unusual usage. I suspect it is a phrasing specific to the domain of Biblical study.

Comment: I have heard "down to the present" used in the same sense. However, I have not heard "downward" used this way. That may be regional variation, or this may be an archaicism.

Answer (score 1):

OED specifically acknowledges this use:

> **A** *adv.*
> **2.** *fig.*
> **b.** Onward from an earlier to a later time.
>
> > 1611   *Bible* (A.V.) Transl. Pref. 3   From Christes time downe~ward.
> > 1679–1714   Bp. G. Burnet *Hist. Reformation* anno 1535 (R.)   From the twelfth century downward.
> > 1849   G. Grote *Hist. Greece* ii. lxvi,   All the old laws of Athens, from Solon downward.

There are expressions like “come down to us” indicating the passage of knowledge or tradition to later generations.

But there is very little if any difference between *downward* in your quote (or the OED citations) and using *onward* or *since*.

Comment: Hi Andrew - would you consider the use of 'downward' as used above as dated or sort of unusual?

Comment: My instinct would be to call it dated, but I've done no research into that aspect of its use other than what I present here. It's something I could imagine my grandparents using, though.

Comment: @AndrewLeach "since" is often used with the present perfect tenses. What about "from...onwards"?

Answer (score 0):

Andrew Leach's answer deals with the OP's question neatly and succinctly. In this response I just want to address the (unasked) question of whether "downward" implies pessimism about the trajectory of the centuries since 1500.

On the face of it, the phrase "down through the ages" (which conveys much the same idea as "downward" here) seems not pessimistic at all, but rather descriptive of, say, an heirloom preserved and passed along from one generation to the next. Visualized as an physical phenomenon, the passing goes from the adult of the earlier generation to the child of the later one—in much the same way that cartoons depict the aged outgoing year handing off the world's responsibilities to the cherubic new year.

Still, downward is the direction of falling or collapsing, which may lead some readers or hearers to suppose that "from the 16th century downward" hints at a darker view of the unfolding of time. (I don't think it does in the particular example that the OP cites, however.) Some similar thought may have influenced Jacob Bronowski's decision to call his documentary series about the development of human society [*The Ascent of Man*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Ascent_of_Man), in contradistinction to Charles Darwin's classic work on evolution, *The Descent of Man*.

One dominant theme of recent centuries has been the championing (by many writers and thinkers) of progress—that is, of improvement of the human condition—as opposed to regression or decline, especially decline due to estrangement from or disobedience toward an increasingly distant, all-powerful creator. Optimists of progress, it seems to me, are unlikely to embrace the notion that time moves "downward" from a more perfect beginning; but since "upward" has never really caught on in connection with time either, they are left with "onward" and "forward" as relatively upbeat ways to talk about movement through time.

This [Ngram graph](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=century+onward%2C+century+onwards%2C+century+forward%2C+century+forwards%2C+century+downward%2C+century+downwards%2C+centuy+upward%2C+century+upwards&year_start=1600&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=0&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccentury%20onward%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccentury%20onwards%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccentury%20forward%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccentury%20forwards%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccentury%20downward%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccentury%20downwards%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccentury%20upwards%3B%2Cc0) of *downward/downwards*, *upward/upwards*, *onward/onwards*, and *forward/forwards* paired with the preceding word *century* shows *downward/downwards* as being quite as common as *onward/onwards* in publications included in the Google Books database, through much of the nineteenth century. But by 1900, both *onward* and *onwards* had outstripped the competition, and over the next 100+ years "century onward/onwards" has maintained its popularity while "century downward/downwards" has sunk to a very low level.

The rise of "century onward/onwards" and the fall of "century downward/downwards" may be unrelated to any societal notion of progress, but the shift in usage is unmistakable.